# UIImageView gets hidden in Xcode8 and Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

My problems is simple: My @IBOutlet UIImageView in my custom UITableViewCell gets hidden if I try to access it via the cellForRowAtIndexpath method.

I've heard that this is either a Swift 3 or Xcode 8 problem (which makes sense because I just now have this problem after updating). I had the same problem with a UIImageView and discovered that the reason it was getting hidden was because I was calling it too early in the cycle. Since the latest update, if I try to access an @IBOutlet from the nib, I can only do so in the viewDidAppear method. If I try in the viewDidLoad or viewWillLoad method, then the outlet gets hidden.

In this case, I am simply changing a UIImageView from a square to a circle via the following two lines of code:

```
cell.pictureImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.pictureImageView.frame.size.width / 2;
cell.pictureImageView.clipsToBounds = true;
```

Again, this works only the vieDidAppear method. Is there a viewDidAppear method for a UITableViewCell? I put the same two lines in the cellForRowAtIndexPath and the image goes away:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.Cell, for: indexPath) as! TimelineTableViewCell

    //Turn profile picture into a circle
    cell.pictureImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.pictureImageView.frame.size.width / 2;
    cell.pictureImageView.clipsToBounds = true;

    return cell
}
```

I also tried it in the custom cell's awakeFromNib method and the same thing happened...the image disappears:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    cell.pictureImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.pictureImageView.frame.size.width / 2;
    cell.pictureImageView.clipsToBounds = true;

}
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks everyone!

Cheers,

C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling it too early. `pictureImageView` has no known `width` yet.
You need to call `layoutIfNeeded`:

```
cell.pictureImageView.layoutIfNeeded()
cell.pictureImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.pictureImageView.frame.size.width / 2
cell.pictureImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

The circle is:

```
    init    
    UIViewController awakeFromNib
    loadView  // your pictureImageView is loaded here
    UIView awakeFromNib
    UIViewController viewDidLoad
    viewWillAppear 
    viewDidAppear // the properties of your pictureImageView are available here
```

Comment: I know I'm calling it early, that's the point. The height and width are set in the storyboard, but if I do so in cellForRow and instantiate the imageview before it gets called naturally, then I lose all of the other preset attributes of the imageview. My question is **when*, in the cycle, does the imageview get instantiated...i.e. what method is it so i can access it.

Comment: call the layoutIfNeeded and you're able to use all the properties earlier as in viewDidAppear

Comment: That's what I've been doing, but I'm trying to avoid forcing the layout. I would like to layout naturally. I'll take a look at the cycle, thanks for providing that!

Comment: Just so it's clear for anyone else that comes to this answer: Call .layoutIfNeeded() prior to setting your view properties in the viewDidLoad.